# Summarizing Subreport Group Sum into Main Report REPORT FOOTER Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have created a Subreport and i would like to add the SubReport Group Sum into my Main Report Footer, i was trying to do it with Shared Variables but it doesn't work the way i want it.

My Main report already have a Running total in the reports' header but i want to include a Running Total
for the Subreport.

I'll appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the way to get an info from the subreport to your main report is with shared variables. Just make sure that you are placing the shared variable in a different section than your subreport. Create a section under your subreport and place your shared variable there and make a running total based on that variable.